# TdxBarManager VCL finding menu options

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

I am looking at a menu option on the all commands tab of a TdxBarMananger. Is there a quick way to find where on the menu the current command is? At present I have to open the dfm file and search for the command name.

Answer (score 2):

You can only search for a bar item by manually expanding sub menus.  There is no a list of conformity which would allow you to quickly  define where a certain BarItem is positioned.